# want the last line when duplicate awk?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have the file:

```
key value

blah blah
blah blah
blahblah
man1 boy1
blah blah
man1 boy2
man1 boy1
```

I  do this to remove duplicate lines:

```
awk '/man1/ { print $1,$2} ' file | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

and the command take the first line and ignore other lines

```
man1 boy1 
man1 boy2
```

but I want to ignore all lines except the last line:

```
man1 boy2 
man1 boy1
```

as ramesh said I want something like:

```
cat filename
blah blah
blah blah
blahblah
man1 boy1
blah blah
man1 boy2
man1 boy1
man1 boy2
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

the desired output

```
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

Comment: Please clarify why the last line is required. Is it because it's adjacent to a similar one? I'm not sure I follow your logic.

Comment: I want it to be like this so I know `boy1` is the last value `man1` take it,see updates

Comment: Is it relevant that `blah blah` is duplicated 3 times? You should really clarify what do you want and provide a better example.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu, no `blah blah` is a not wanted text see updates

Comment: Are you doing `print $1,$2` because you want to discard text (if any) beyond the second word? Because, if not, your `awk '/man1/ { print $1,$2} ' file | awk '!x[$0]++'` can be compressed down to `awk '/foo/ && !x[$0]++' file`.

Comment: Is this some type of homework problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/man1/{pos[$0] = NR}
END {
  for(key in pos) reverse[pos[key]] = key
  for(nr=1;nr<=NR;nr++)
    if(nr in reverse) print reverse[nr]
}' yourfile
```

Output:

```
[root@host ~]# sh shell.sh
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

[Source](http://backreference.org/2011/11/17/remove-duplicates-but-keeping-only-the-last-occurrence/)

Answer (score 8):

```
tac filename |awk '/man1/ { print $1,$2} '| awk '!x[$0]++' | tac
```

**Testing**

I wanted to test with more concrete input. So, my testing is as below.

```
cat filename
blah blah
blah blah
blahblah
man1 boy1
blah blah
man1 boy2
man1 boy1
man1 boy2
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

Now, I run the above command and get the output as,

```
tac filename |awk '/man1/ { print $1,$2} '| awk '!x[$0]++' | tac
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

As per Steeldriver's suggestion, we could modify the `awk` to be more simpler as,

```
tac filename | awk '/^man1/ && !x[$2]++' | tac
```

Comment: +1 good one, but I want to ask you is tac will be bad for performance for large files, I remove the duplicates because I don't want bad performance.

Comment: `tac` is actually a lazy solution :)

Comment: Do you really need two awks? What about `tac file | awk '/^man1/ && !x[$2]++' | tac`

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks. I will check out this option as soon as I get a Linux box and update the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ${(Oau)${(MOa)${(f)"$(<file)"}:#man1*}}
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

Those are *parameter expansion flags*:

- `f`: split on newline
- `${(M)array:#pattern}`: expands to the elements matching the pattern
- `Oa`: reverse the order of array
- `u`: unique

Answer (score 3):

A GNU awk specific solution:

```
gawk '
    $1 == "man1" {
        # remember the last line number
        x[$0] = NR
    } 
    END {
        # traverse the array by sorted numeric values
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
        for (line in x) 
            print line
    }
' file
```

```
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

As a terse one-liner:

```
gawk '/man1/{x[$0]=NR}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for(l in x)print l}' file
```

References:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning

Answer (score 2):

A two pass solution. In the first pass capture the record numbers of the last record for each key into an array. In the second pass, print if record number exists in the array

```
awk 'NR == FNR{if ($0 ~ /man/)x[$0]=NR; next};
     FNR == 1{for (k in x) y[x[k]]=k};
     (FNR in y)' file file
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to mention the file name twice

```
awk '!/man1/{next}; NR == FNR {a[$0]++; next}; ++b[$0] == a[$0]' file file
```

Comment: `$ cat sam2
blah blah
blah blah
blahblah
man1 boy1
blah blah
man1 boy2
man1 boy1
man1 boy2
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
$ awk 'NR == FNR && /man1/ {a[$0]++; next} NR != FNR && ++b[$0] == a[$0]' sam2 sam2
man1 boy1
man1 boy3
man1 boy4
man1 boy2
$
`